# How to change text color after fixing the word limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to change my contenteditable element text color after a fixed character limit how should I do this.Like before 140 characters text will be black but after 140 characters whatever text will be written that will automatically change to red color.

```
function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
    var range, selection;
    range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
    selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
    selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
}

elem = document.getElementById('my-content');

elem.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) {
    var _evt = evt;
    setTimeout(function() {
        _evt = _evt || window.event;
        var charCode = _evt.keyCode || _evt.which;
        $("#my-content").lettering('words');
        setEndOfContenteditable(elem);
    }, 10, _evt);
}, false);
```

Comment: can you please post more clarification about your question? post image or demo of what you are working with?

Comment: before 140 characters text will be black but after 140 characters text written will automatically change to red color

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the input, change the color if it's higher than what you want:

```
if (elem.value.length > 140) {
    elem.style.color = 'red';
} else {
    elem.style.color = 'black';
}
```

I don't really understand the question, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: before 140 characters text will be black but after 140 characters text written will automatically change to red color

Comment: Pretty crazy, that's actually the example I randomly wrote out. Does it make sense to you?